# AdminLTE + symfony2 -> Unable to find file

Tags: php, symfony

I tried to install the adminlte bundle but with no luck. Ive always get:

```
Unable to find file "@AvanzuAdminThemeBundle/Resources/public/vendor/modernizr/modernizr.js" in . (which is being imported from "app\cache\dev/assetic/routing.yml").
```

things ive done:
Added this to the composer.json

```
   {
        "require": {
            "avanzu/admin-theme-bundle": "~1.3"
        }
    }
```

then `php composer.phar require avanzu/admin-theme-bundle`
added  `new Avanzu\AdminThemeBundle\AvanzuAdminThemeBundle(),` to the AppKernel

Copy everything with `app/console assets:install --symlink`

Then went to the base.html.twig and added 
`{% extends 'AvanzuAdminThemeBundle:layout:base-layout.html.twig' %}`

If i start the server i get those error. The files are located here:

```
./vendor/avanzu/admin-theme-bundle/Resources/public/static/dev/scripts/modernizr.js
./vendor/avanzu/admin-theme-bundle/Resources/public/static/prod/scripts/modernizr.js
./web/bundles/avanzuadmintheme/static/dev/scripts/modernizr.js
./web/bundles/avanzuadmintheme/static/prod/scripts/modernizr.js
```

Whats my fault? Thanks!

Comment: seems an open issue: https://github.com/avanzu/AdminThemeBundle/issues/46

Answer (score 0):

You have to fetch all the vendors as well :

php app/console avanzu:admin:fetch-vendor

[Here](https://github.com/avanzu/AdminThemeBundle) is the documentation.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command to create all the symlinks

`php bin/console assets:install --symlink`

OR

`php app/console assets:install --symlink`